# pgfplots function which touches the edges of the plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to plot the constant y = pi function with the plot touching both sides of the plot.

I have had a search through the `pgfplots` manual without much luck. I have tried `\addplot{3.141...}` which produces a small line spanning very little of the x axis, and manually plotting points for the range of my graph.

Comment: You can use the `addplot` command as you are currently doing. Just add `enlargelimits=false` as an option to your `axis` environments.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem.  This would also ensure that the solutions provided would be compatible with the way you are using them.

Comment: How about `\addplot expression[domain=-10:10]{pi};`
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways to achieve what you want, depending on what you mean by "touching both sides of the plot".

You can add an extra y tick. Or, you can add a plot that is constant either by using `coordinates` or `function`. The coordinates one needs the `xmin` and `xmax` to be specified.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$\arctan(x)$},
    extra y ticks={0.785},
    extra y tick labels={$\pi/4$},
    extra y tick style={grid=major},
    minor y tick num=1,
    domain=-5:5,
    samples=100]
    \addplot+[no marks] function {atan(x)};
    \addplot+[no marks] function {pi/2};
    \addplot+[no marks] coordinates {(-5,pi) (5,pi)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I was after, Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have either of the following two as an option:

```
\begin{axis}
  \begin{pgfplotsinterruptdatabb}
    \addplot[forget plot] coordinates {(-16000,3.14) (16000,3.14)};
  \end{pgfplotsinterruptdatabb}
\end{axis}
```

or

```
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[forget plot,update limits=false] coordinates {(-16000,3.14) (16000,3.14)};
\end{axis}
```

The first I would prefer. You can then easily do:

```
\newcommand\addplotpi[1][]{
  \begin{pgfplotsinterruptdatabb}
    \addplot[forget plot,#1] coordinates {(-16000,3.14) (16000,3.14)};
  \end{pgfplotsinterruptdatabb}
}
```

and simply use that in every `axis` environment you wish to utilize it in.

The `forget plot` allows you to add it in the beginning of an `axis` environment without disturbing the color-lists and legends.

The only thing you should worry about is the lower and upper limit of `x`. But just do it large enough so that it wont bother you! :)